# Subdomain not opening in firefox

Tags: linux, google-chrome, firefox, vhosts

Not able to run my application using localhost subdomain ex: **abc.localhost**. It works fine in Chrome but not working in Firefox/IE

This is how my vhost entry looks like. I have also tried ServerAlias name but nothing seems to be working. Any leads would be highly appreciated.

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
   # The name to respond to
   ServerName abc.localhost
   # Folder where the files live
   DocumentRoot "<PATH">
   # A few helpful settings...
   <Directory "<PATH>"
           Options -Indexes
   </Directory>
   <IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
  </IfModule>
      #ErrorDocument 404 /web/page-not-found.php
   #ErrorDocument 500 /web/maintenance.php
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^/assets/(.*)       -                        [L,QSA]
   RewriteRule ^/web/(.*)          -                        [L,QSA]
   RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico       -                        [L,QSA]
   RewriteRule ^/(.*).js       -                        [L,QSA]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$              /index.php?__req__url=$1 [B,L,QSA]
   # Apache will look for these two files, in this order, if no file is specified in the URL
   DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Comment: Try adding `php_value opcache.enable 0` at the end of .htaccess file